# If $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+ax+1=0$ has at least one real solution then find all such set of $(a,b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Question is the same as the title. We have to find all such values of $(a,b)$ where $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+ax+1=0$ has at least one real solution.
I tried to solve it in the methods of theory of equation. That is we can write the sum of roots equal to $(-a)$ . In this way I tried. Then I suppose the first root is real and the other may or may not be real. So I made four cases. But I can't process. Somebody help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is useful to notice that your polynomial is a palyndromic polynomial. If we set $z=x+\frac{1}{x}$,

$$ x^4+ax^3+bx^2+ax+1 = x^2\cdot\left[ z^2-az+(b-2)\right]. $$
The original polynomial has a real root **iff** $q(z)=z^2-az+(b-2)$ has a real root in $[2,\infty)$ or a real root in $(-\infty,-2]$. Can you find which constraints on $a,b$ grant that $q(z)$ has a root there?
This equivalent problem deals with the intersections of a fixed parabola and a variable line.